# $A$ and $B$ closed in $\Bbb R^2$ but neither is compact

Tags: elementary-set-theory, compactness

I haven't been able to find a proper example to solve item c. Item b is shown so that the context is clear.

b. If $A$ is closed, $B$ is compact, and $A \cap B=\emptyset$ , prove that there is $d > 0$ such that $|x-y|\geq d$ for all $y\in A$ and $x\in B$.

c. Give a counterexample in $\Bbb R^2$ if $A$ and $B$ are closed but neither is compact.

Comment: Good examples of closed sets are graphs of continuous functions. Can you think of two of those that don't intersect, but get closer than any small $d$?

Comment: Is this problem from Spivak, by any chance?

Comment: Indeed, it's from Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds".

Comment: Thought I recognized it! That's a very good book :)

Comment: Does $A=\{(x,y): y=1/x^2, \forall x>0 \}$ and $B=\{(x,y): y=1/x^2, \forall x<0 \}$ serve as a counter example.

Comment: Well..... if we choose a very small $d$, then your set $A$ contains the point $(d/4,d^2/16)$, and your set $B$ contains the point $(-d/4, d^2/16)$. What can you conclude from that?

Comment: That for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find points arbitrarily close, which imply that, in the terms of item b, there is no $d>0$ dividing the two sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint, think about what you lose by assuming the sets are closed but neither is compact (that is, think about how we characterize compact sets in $R^2$).  Both sets lack something that you can use to your advantage.